# How to set the interval of my UISlider such that it shows the value only in some whole numbers

Tags: iphone, uislider

In my app I want to set the `interval` of `slider`. I have a `slider` which shows the value in the bubble and I want to display the value only in some whole numbers. Let's say if I have `min` and `max` value of `0-1000` and I want to increase the value by `25` and not like 1-2-3-4.
Any suggestions??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the slider use its natural range internally, and simply convert the value for output by multiplying it by the increment. For a 0-1000 slider, you'd set the `maximumValue` property to 40 (that's 1000 / 25) and then multiply that value by 25 to get the output value.

Answer (score 1):

try.

```
//fix slider value =0;

//some method to run slider value  0-1000 
{
slider.value=slider.value+25;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `UISlider`, probably called `StepSlider` which has a single property `stepSize`. Relevant `UISlider` properties would be overriden to bridge the values between the consumer of the class and the superclass. Example [`source`](http://pastie.org/1963429),